# How to find the minimum of $xy$ from the equation $2x+y+6=xy$ , $x,y>0$

Tags: maxima-minima, completing-the-square

I have tried doing factoring and completing the square and also AM-GM

$(2-y)(x-1)=-8$

$xy=2x+y+6≥\sqrt{12xy} $

Comment: How about using calculus?

Comment: So notice that you can rewrite the original as
$$
y = \frac{2x+6}{x-1}
$$
What do you know about $xy$ now?

Comment: Sorry don't know much calculus only in year 9 this is just me trying to get ahead only know basic derivative stuff like power rule unfortunately.

Comment: xy=x(2x+6)/(x-1) I'll have a think

Comment: Why do you think $xy$ has a minimum for the given equation?

Comment: because its a question I tried tackling as a challenge for myself and I can't solve it found it on the internet.

Comment: please consider $x=-1000$, what is the value of $y$? So what is $xy$? Now check with $x = -10000$. Unless there is constraint on values of $x$, there is no minimum.

Comment: Oh sorry yeah x could be complex real etc. yeah its x is restricted to the domain of postive real numbers

Comment: Yes if both $x, y \geq 0$, there is a minimum $xy = 18$. If both $x, y \leq 0$, there is a minimum $xy = 2$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118637/discussion-between-tom-xia-and-math-lover).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AM-GM works perfectly fine with a small trick.
$2x+y+6=xy \Rightarrow y(x-1)=2x+6 \Rightarrow y = \dfrac{2x+6}{x-1} \Rightarrow xy =\dfrac{2x^2+6x}{x-1}$.

As @Yves Daoust points out $\dfrac{2x^2+6x}{x-1} = 2x+8+ \dfrac{8}{x-1} = 2(x-1)+10+\dfrac{8}{x-1} $.

But by AM-GM,  $ 2(x-1)+10+\dfrac{8}{x-1} \geq 10 + 2\left(\sqrt{2(x-1) \cdot \dfrac{8}{x-1} } \right)  = 10+2\sqrt{16}=18$. This is indeed the minimum of $xy$.

Comment: Wait how is (2x^2+6x)/(x-1) = 2x+8+8/(x-1)?

Comment: Ahh. polynomial long division

Comment: @Tom Xia Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

With $p:=xy$, after elimination of $y$ the equation can be written

$$p=\frac{2x^2+6x}{x-1},$$ with $x,p>0$.

---

Note that

$$\frac{2x^2+6x}{x-1}=2x+8+\frac 8{x-1},$$ and finding the extrema is easy by differentiation.

Comment: Do you take the derivative of this?

Comment: @TomXia: yep, that's a way.

Comment: Huh i got this (2(x^2-3-2x))/(x-1)^2 after taking the derivative

Comment: don't you find the critical point by making it 0?